# Why is wait_event_interruptible() in Linux kernel never used in a while loop?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, mutex, interrupt

Looking through the Linux kernel, I found the return value of `wait_event_interruptible()` is almost always checked by an `if`-block instead of a while loop:

```
if (mutex_lock_interruptible(lock)) {
  return -ERESTARTSYS;
}
```

Why not check the return value in a while loop and keep trying even if the wait was interrupted by a signal handler? Why would the driver writer want to return `-ERESTARTSYS` for the system call to restart? Isn't this more expensive?

```
while (mutex_lock_interruptible(lock)) {
  // 
}
```

Comment: So is the question about `wait_event_interruptible()` or `mutex_lock_interruptible()`?

Answer (score 1):

The system call has to return so userspace can handle the signal. If you were using a while loop, this would render the wait uninterruptible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Somehow I was imagining the task running in kernel mode is also interruptible by signals. So the mutex_lock_interruptible() call being interrupted by a signal simply means a signal has arrived and lock was not acquired, and it's up to the driver writer to determine whether to return to user mode for handling the signal or not?

Comment: The driver would certainly not act on a signal and will leave the action to userspace. So the driver already knows before the wait whether it can be interrupted so it can call the proper interruptible or non interruptible wait/mutex.